# Is this SQL the most efficient way

Tags: sql

We have a table that converts SAT scores into ACT scores using a year. if the data changes in the future we would add the new scores along with the year the scores change. We need to pass in a year and sat score and return the correct act score.

sample data with three rows would be

```
act sat year
28 1010 1998
29 1010 2012
30 1010 2015
```

If I pass in a SAT score of 1010 and a year of 2014 I should return an act score of 29 back.

I wrote the following SQL statement that works.

```
select act, 
       RANK() OVER(ORDER BY year DESC) 
from keessattbl 
where sat = 1010 and INT(year) <= 2014 
FETCH FIRST ROW ONLY
```

Is this the most efficient way to handle this.

Thanks in advance Doug

Comment: If you post code, XML or data samples, **PLEASE** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Comment: Thank you.  I was not sure how to do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another option would be to use the following:

```
select k1.*
from keessattbl k1
where k1.sat = 1010
and k1.year = (select max(k2.year) 
               from keessattbl k2
               where k2.sat = k1.sat
                 and k2.year <= 2014)
```

You will need to check which one is more efficient. If `year` (and possibly `sat`) is indexed, then both are probably quite fast.

But you will need to look at the execution plan (or simply time the statements) to find out.

Comment: Thanks, I will run some time test on yours and mine to see which is faster. I will update with the answer.

Comment: Strange. It works for me on Oracle and PostgreSQL with the sample data you provided. Can you edit your question and add the table's definition (especially the datatypes for each column)?

Comment: I am sorry, I made a small mistake when I copied your code to DB2.  It does work. I did a visual explain, and your code actually runs a little faster than mine even though your code is asking me for a new index to be added (year) and mine isn't.  If I were to add the index it would run even faster i am sure. Thanks.

Comment: Since there is only a small amount of difference in the time it takes to execute these statements, It becomes user preference.

Answer (score 0):

I would say "Sure." Is it not performing well?

Also, most DBMS's have some way to get the first row of a result set, so you don't need to use DB2 unless you want to.

Comment: I have never used the RANK() function before and did not know if there is a lot of overhead in using it. I have seen where people have joined a table with itself to get the same result.

Comment: Sorry, I don't have any significant DB2 experience, so I can't really discuss the RANK function.

Comment: I don't think the RANK() function is just DB2

Comment: Well, I've never heard of it, but that doesn't mean anything :)

Comment: rank() is ANSI standard. It's called a windowing function. A lot of DBMS support that.

Comment: No kidding... I'll have to look that up. Thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 0):

if you are not sure if it's the most efficient way to write then you can check by doing an EXPLAIN on the query. write the query another way, do an EXPLAIN on it and compare the costs. IBM provides the IBM Data Studio product for free. you can just right-click on your sql and select Visual Explain to get the results in the gui.

Comment: I ran my query using visual explain and it seems to run fast and does not suggest any new indexes.